# Custom Regex Replacement in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to find all patterns in a string that match the regex: no="(\d+)" 
then replace the digits in the group with something else.

In the method below I can find and replace the entire match, but that is not what I want.
Is there a way to replace just a portion in that match?

```
private String replaceStringFromPatternSearch(String stringToSearch, String patternString, String replacementString) {
    String replacedString = null;
    Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher stringMatcher = stringPattern.matcher(stringToSearch);
    replacedString = stringMatcher.replaceAll(replacementString);
    if (replacedString != null) {
        return replacedString;
    } else {
        return stringToSearch;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give sample input/output

Comment: See accepted solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25047477/1382300

Comment: Hi philip, your regex will replace any long number. What exactly you want, please give an example

Comment: I have given example data in the answer that I posted myself. The way I am implementing this allows me to use the same regex to search for a string in one string and then replace it in another.
String1 : <detail type="07" time="100611" no="1111111111" detail">
String2 : <detail type="07" time="100611" no="07040365089" detail">
So I can pull out 1111111111 from String1 and replace 07040365089 with it in String2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both of these methods solve my problem:

Example Data: <detail type="07" time="100611" no="07040365089" detail">

with the idea that I want to replace 07040365089 with something else.
no="\d" occurs multiple times in the actual data.
There are other replacements that are required for different patterns.

```
private String replaceStringFromPatternSearch2(String stringToSearch, String patternString, String replacementString) {
    String replacedString = "";
    Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    int startSearch = 0;
    Matcher stringMatcher = stringPattern.matcher(stringToSearch);
    while (stringMatcher.find(startSearch)) {
        int start = stringMatcher.start(1);
        int end = stringMatcher.end(1);
        replacedString += stringToSearch.substring(startSearch, start) + replacementString + stringToSearch.substring(end);
        startSearch = end + 1;
    }
    if (!replacedString.isEmpty()) {
        return replacedString;
    } else {
        return stringToSearch;
    }
}

private String replaceStringFromPatternSearch(String stringToSearch, String patternString, String replacementString) {
    String replacedString = "";
    Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    int startSearch = 0;
    Matcher stringMatcher = stringPattern.matcher(stringToSearch);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (stringMatcher.find()) {
        String wholeGroup = stringMatcher.group(0);
        replacedString = wholeGroup.replace(stringMatcher.group(1), replacementString);
        stringMatcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacedString);
    }
    stringMatcher.appendTail(sb);
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return stringToSearch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

### No Callbacks / Lambdas in Java Replace, But We Have Other Options

**Option 1: Use Capture Buffers in Replacement Function**

In `replaceAll`, you can build your replacement from components such as captured text and strings you want to insert at that time. Here is an example:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("no=\"(\\d+)\"", 
                                         "Something $1 Something else");
```

In the replacement, `$1` are the captured digits. You don't have to use them, but as you can see you can build a replacement string around them.

**Option 2 (Replacement Lambda/Callback/Delegate Equivalent): Build it One Match At a Time**

In Java, to build even more sophisticated replacement, we don't have replacement lambdas, but we can do this:

```
StringBuffer resultString = new StringBuffer();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("no=\"(\\d+)\"");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // You can vary the replacement text for each match on-the-fly
        // String computed_replacement = .... Something wild!
        regexMatcher.appendReplacement(resultString, computed_replacement );
    } 
regexMatcher.appendTail(resultString);
```

Comment: thanks, this approach put me on the right track for a more effective solution than substringing with the start and end of the group

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookarounds, so that the matches will only be the digits:

```
(?<=no=")\d+(?=")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7S460SU3DXKiMuKf)