# Java Regex to replace only part of string (url)

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace only numeric section of a string. Most of the cases it's either full URL or part of URL, but it can be just a normal string as well.

- `/users/12345` becomes `/users/XXXXX`
- `/users/234567/summary` becomes `/users/XXXXXX/summary`
- `/api/v1/summary/5678` becomes `/api/v1/summary/XXXX`
- `http://example.com/api/v1/summary/5678/single` becomes `http://example.com/api/v1/summary/XXXX/single`

Notice that I am not replacing `1` from `/api/v1`

So far, I have only following which seem to work in most of the cases:

```java
input.replaceAll("/[\\d]+$", "/XXXXX").replaceAll("/[\\d]+/", "/XXXXX/");
```

But this has 2 problems:

- The replacement size doesn't match with the original string length.
- The replacement character is hardcoded.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(/|(?!^)\\G)\\d(?=\\d*(?:/|$))", "$1X");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2C9Ma/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `(/|(?!^)\\G)`: Match `/` or end of the previous match (but not at start) in capture group #1
- `\\d`: Match a digit
- `(?=\\d*(?:/|$))`: Ensure that digits are followed by a `/` or end.
- **Replacement:** `$1X`: replace it with capture group #1 followed by `X`

Comment: Very nice, but you'll need to close on either a slash or the end of string in order to avoid matching numbers followed by non-numeric characters.

Comment: Sure, `(/|(?!^)\G)\d(?=\d*(?:/|$))` can be used to ensure that but this case wasn't specifically mentioned in OP's requirements.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted the OP's first sentence: "I want to replace only numeric section of a string."

Answer (score 0):

Not a `Java` guy here but the idea should be transferrable. Just capture a `/`, digits and `/` optionally, count the length of the second group and but it back again.

So

```
(/)(\d+)(/?)
```

becomes

```
$1XYZ$3
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Fjgfxk/2) and [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25052668/1231450) for a lambda equivalent to e.g. `Python` or `PHP`.

Comment: Thanks Jan for the reply. But Java regex are little different than other languages are not really mapped 1-1. There is another answer by @anubhava which works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need something like this :

```java
String new_s1 = s3.replaceAll("(\\/)(\\d)+(\\/)?", "$1XXXXX$3");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this does not solve any of the 2 problems mentioned in the question. Please refer to @anubhava's answer which works perfectly for these.

Comment: Indeed, he provided the best answer. Hat off!